# Kafka producer not distributing messages over partitions

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I am creating kafka topic as following:

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper xx.xxx.xx:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 200 --topic test6 --config retention.ms=900000
```

and then I produce messages with golang using the following library:

```
    "gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka"
```

the producer configuration looks like this:

```
    for _, message := range bigslice {

    topic := "test6"
        p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic},
            Value:          []byte(message),
        }, nil)

        }
```

the problem that I've sent more than 200K messages but they all lands in partition 0.

what could be wrong in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages with the same key are being added to the same partition. If this is not the case, then try to include `Partition: kafka.PartitionAny`:

```
for _, message := range bigslice {

    topic := "test6"
        p.Produce(&kafka.Message{
            TopicPartition: kafka.TopicPartition{Topic: &topic, Partition: kafka.PartitionAny},
            Value: []byte(message),
        }, nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You provide no key when producing, so it goes to the same partition. I suggest you to read at least this https://medium.com/event-driven-utopia/understanding-kafka-topic-partitions-ae40f80552e8